# how to read .pkcs12 certificate installed on android 7 version

Tags: android, xamarin

I have hit the roadblock and scratching my head from one week. I have also did lot of googling but did not find any answer so need you help on this.

I am generating .pkcs12 Client Side Certificate using openssl and installing it on Android 7 device, which gets stored in Android ”Credential Storage/User credentials”. In the previous versions(5.0) of Android device these certificates were installed under ”Credential Storage/Trusted credentials”.

I have used below code to read it from trusted credentials in android 5.

```
            Java.Security.KeyStore _keyStore = Java.Security.KeyStore.GetInstance("AndroidCAStore");

            if (_keyStore != null)
            {
                _keyStore.Load(null, null);
                Java.Util.IEnumeration _aliases = _keyStore.Aliases();
                while (_aliases.HasMoreElements)
                {
                    String _alias = (String)_aliases.NextElement();
                    Java.Security.Cert.X509Certificate _cert = (Java.Security.Cert.X509Certificate)_keyStore.GetCertificate(_alias);                        
                    var _commonNameIndex = _cert.IssuerDN.Name.IndexOf("CN");
                    if (_commonNameIndex > -1)
                    {
                        var _commonNameStartValue = _cert.IssuerDN.Name.Substring(_commonNameIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I want to read the client certificate installed on android 7 .

Thanks,
Vinod

Comment: Why are you not using `System.Security` instead?

Comment: The Keystore.GetInstance method is returning java.security object and typecasting it into system.security was not happening.

Comment: any update? @VinodMG

Comment: Did you find any answer ?